# When running a program using Process.Start, it can't find it's resource files

Tags: c#, graphics, process

i have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/Users/Valy/Desktop/3dcwrelease/3dcw.exe";
    p.Start();
}
```

`3dcw.exe` is an app for OpenGL graphics.

The problem is that when I click on the button, the executable file runs, but it can't access its texture files.

Does anyone have a solution? I think something like loading the bitmap files in the background, then running the exe file, but how can i do that?

Comment: Where do you set the image to be loaded?

Comment: Grant Winney - The images are in the OpenGL app. The textures which i used to do that app. If i run the exe manualy, works, but i run from c# interface, run, but it doesn't load the texture(images/bmp files). And i don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've searched on the internet for a solution at your problem and found this site: http://www.widecodes.com/0HzqUVPWUX/i-am-lauching-an-opengl-program-exe-file-from-visual-basic-but-the-texture-is-missing-what-is-wrong.html

In C# code it looks something like this:

```
string exepath = @"C:\Users\Valy\Desktop\3dcwrelease\3dcw.exe";
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = exepath;
psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(exepath);
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: The key point is `WorkingDirectory`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely that the *3dcw.exe* is looking for files from it's current working directory. When you run an application using `Process.Start`, the current working directory for that application will default to `%SYSTEMROOT%\system32`. The program probably expects a different directory, most likely the directory in which the executable file is located.

You can set the working directory for the process using the code below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "C:/Users/Valy/Desktop/3dcwrelease/3dcw.exe";

    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

    processStartInfo.FileName = path;
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    Process.Start(processStartInfo);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. same thing. OpenGL app run , initialize OpenGL interface, but the terrain doesn't load, because it doesn't find the bmp file. Can i do a method to open the folder where is the app?

Comment: it doesn't find "p" from p.Start()

Comment: I updated the code to show the entire working example. Give it another try.

Comment: p.Start(processStartInfo);  return this error: "Error1 Member 'System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference "

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Diagnostics;    i have this namespaces, i need more one?